# Ruby on rails - undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, haml

Every time I submit the form I get this error: `` undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass ``. If everything is correct I can submit the form without any problems, but when there is one thing missing it gives me that error. The error sends me to this line:

views/users/new.html.haml

```
- @subscriptions.each do |fbs|
  = fb.radio_button :subscription_id, fbs.id, class: 'radiobtn', required: true
```

controllers/users_controller.rb

```
def new
  @user = Users::Business.new
  @subscriptions = Businesses::Subscription.all
end

def create
  @user = Users::Business.new(user_params)

  if @user.save
    sign_in(@user)
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: Submitting the form will call the controller's `create` action, how does it look like? I suspect that you call `render "new"` and don't set `@subscriptions`.

Comment: did you have some deprecated warnings about TopLevel constant in rails console? if yes, try to use @subscriptions = ::Businesses::Subscription.all

Comment: Thank's for the edit. Like I suspected: you render the `new` template from within `create` but you don't set `@subscriptions` as required by the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigns subscriptions in a create action too:

```
before_filter :set_subscriptions, only: %w(new create) #for edit and update if needed

private
def set_subscriptions
  @subscriptions = Businesses::Subscription.all
end
```

Or add `@subscriptions = Businesses::Subscription.all` directly to `create` action after the saving is failed and you re-render `new` form.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because there is no value persisted with that model . 
You can check the data into the `rails console`
like ,

```
$rails console
> Businesses::Subscription.count
```

And if you see that there is no data then you can write a `if ... end` block to check for null value and handle it.

Comment: `Businesses::Subscription.all` never returns `nil`.

Comment: i agree with Stefan. It returns empty relation, not nil